# Method to extract all existing combination in two columns

Tags: r

I prepared a simple code for my question due to the original data volume is huge.

```
df <- data.frame(X=c(0,0,1,1,1,1),Y=c(0,0,0,0,1,1),Z=c(1.5,2,5,0.7,3.5,4.2))
```

I'm trying to extract all actually existing combinations in columns X and Y. So the expected result will be (0,0),(1,0),(1,1).

But, If I utilize `expand.grid`, it will return all available combinations mathematically with elements 0 & 1. So (0,1) will be included in the result

So my question is how to extract only actually existing combinations in two different columns?
Any opinion is welcome!

Comment: Do you mean something like this `df[!duplicated(df[, 1:2]), 1:2]`?

Answer (score 0):

We can subset the relevant columns and then use `unique` over it.

```
unique(df[c('X', 'Y')])

#  X Y
#1 0 0
#3 1 0
#5 1 1
```

Or in `dplyr`, use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% distinct(X, Y)
```